# Add external reference to project template

Tags: visual-studio, project-template

> I have Project name `P1` and I add to it `Automapper.dll` as reference
>
> when Export the project as template then make new project with this
>   template the `automapper.dll` is broken
>
> how I can make project template  get this dll?

Answer (score 0):

Add dll reference in new project also.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click Automapper.dll  from Project P1.
- choose properties.
- Turn on to 'True' for Property name 'Copy local'.
- Build project and try your stuff. It should copy along with that.